# Customize TexMaker auto-completion to only insert labels with prefix

Tags: texmaker

When writing a document, I usually use prefixes for my labels to keep track of different types of labels, e.g. eq: for equations or fig: for figures. I know that I can define my command completion in TexMaker, but I could not find a way to do the following:

When I start typing \eqref, I would like to only get labels starting with eq: as completion option.

If I define the command completion as \eqref{#label#}, then the drop down menu for label completion will offer me all labels in the whole document. If I try something like \eqref{eq:#label#}, then the completion will try to add the full label after "eq:", resulting in labels like "eq:eq:1". \eqref{eq:@} will not offer to autocomplete the labels.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour in TexMaker?